# Conditional Select in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to create a table in SAS, which is a subset of a larger table. I am using the following chart as an example. As you can see, columnA has 501 and 502 repeated twice. What I want is to select the row with the max number in ColumnB. The second chart is the result that I would like to have.

Chart 1

```
A       B       C

501     1       O

502     1       K

503     1       V

501     2       Y

502     2       U

504     1       I
```

Chart 2

```
A       B       C

503     1       V

501     2       Y

502     2       U

504     1       I
```

What I am thinking right now is:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE CHART2 AS
SELECT
C.COLUMNA,
C.COLUMNC
FROM CHART1 C;
QUIT;
```

I am not sure how to say that when there is a duplicate rows in columnA, only select the rows where columnB has the max number. The formatting of the table is a little bit weirdo. I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `having` clause in `proc sql`.  Think of it as a filter that gets applied after any groupings have been done.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select *
  from sashelp.class
  group by sex
  having age = max(age)
  ;
quit;
```

In the above code, we are keeping the rows where the age value on the row is equal to the maximum age (`max(age)`) for that sex (as we are grouping by sex).

You will notice in the results that for Females we get two rows returned because there were two records that had an age equal to the max female age, but only one row for Males.

Without more details about your data I can't be certain that this will exactly fit your needs but it may.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you very much! I was using max in the select sentence, which looks like select columnA, max(coumnB) from chart1 group by columnA. However, it only works when I don't include columnC in the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
PROC SORT data = Chart1;
  by A descending B;
RUN;

DATA Chart2;
  set Chart1;
  by A;
  if first.A then output;
RUN;
```

The first step sorts your data by ascending order of A and then by descending order of B. The second step keeps only the first row for each value of A.